# Moving points in QGis by typing coordinates

Tags: qgis, point, layers

I have a .shp point layer created starting from a .csv file in which I have coordinates in GG°MM'SS".
It usually happens I need to update a point position with new coords they give me in GG°MM'SS" format.

If I open the attribute table and I change the coords, the point doesn't move so I only have the attribute updated. How can I move the points typing new coords so they are both updated in position and attribute table.

Actually I must open the .csv file each time, I update the coords and then I create the layer again by importing the .csv file then save the file in .shp.
It sound strange to me you couldn't do this in a simpler way.

Comment: Rightclicking a point with the `node tool` in edit mode allows you to manipulate the coordinates as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

As @Erik said there is the Vertex tool to set the position based on coordinate.

[image]

Then half the problem is solved for you. You just need to create a virtual field that will contain the coordinate base on the geometry of your point.

Here is the formula :

```
 to_dms( $x , 'x', 0)
 to_dms( $y , 'y', 0)
```

Comment: This is a News to me, but still too complicated. What kind of coords are the ones in the Vertex Editor Window? It should be nicer if those coord should be in DMS to make move more intuitive. Too many steps to do and I find too slow if you have a lot of points to edit...

Comment: The coordinate format will be in the coordinate system you use as projection in your layer. If your layer is in a coordinate system that use Degrees then it should work.